# Rails 5: query has_many / belongs_to namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have `has_many / belongs_to` relationship:

*models/media/media.rb*

```
module Media
  class Media < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :media, class_name: 'Position::Position'
end
```

In Media::Media I have column `name`

*models/position/position.rb*

```
module Position
  class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :media, optional: true, inverse_of: :position, class_name: 'Media::Media', foreign_key: 'media_id'
end
```

In Position::Position I have column `media_id`.

I'm a bit stuck with relatively simple thing: **how to show Media `name` for each `position`?** Thank you for any help! I'm on Rails 5 and Postgresql 9.5.

**Update**

In console I try this: `Position::Position.joins(:media).where(media_id: :id).select(:name)` however I get this error: `(Object doesn't support #inspect)`

Comment: You need array with names?

Comment: @Mihalko Farhat In view I need to have dropdown list with Media names and when particular Media is selected I need to load associated Positions. I thought there can be a way working with Position model, querying back to Media just to grab those Media names by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the join maybe - Media::Media.joins(:positions)

Comment: Thank you, however it gives an error as well: `(Object doesn't support #inspect)`

Comment: Also having the module named exactly as the class could cause problems, could you rename the dir and modules to plural ? (e.g module medias and dir name medias..same for positions)

Comment: Do you really think this is the case? I generated model like media/media with media.rb in models where I have this inside:
`module Media
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'media_'
  end
end`

Comment: I think I found solution, which the most likely is related to column names I have in tables. I'm having some plural names, where I had to do singular. I'll check and post if that worked.

Comment: I have to admit - you were right. Not only your suggested reversing join worked (when I had columns with right names), but I had to change to Positions::Positions (module, class). It appeared that Media::Media can stay as is as "Media" can be plural as well. Thank you for help and I'm upvoting your answer!